# how to delete a particular object withiin an array by specifying the its position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an object like below. In that i need to delete a particular object within the array named "cards".

```
var lists = [
    {
        "cards": [
            {
                "cardDesc": "a",
                "cardTitle": "a",
                "comments": "a"
            },
            {
                "cardDesc": "b",
                "cardTitle": "b",
                "comments": "b"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cards": [
            {
                "cardDesc": "c",
                "cardTitle": "c",
                "comments": "c"
            },
            {
                "cardDesc": "d",
                "cardTitle": "d",
                "comments": "d"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

i tried like below. it did not work.

```
$scope.lists[0].cards.pop(x);
$scope.lists[0].cards.slice(x,1);
```

where x is position of a specific object within cards.

waiting your response.

Comment: `.slice` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.splice()`, not `.slice()`. `slice` returns a new array containing the selected elements), `splice` modifies the given array by removing the selected elements (and returning them as well).

```js
var lists = [
    {
        "cards": [
            {
                "cardDesc": "a",
                "cardTitle": "a",
                "comments": "a"
            },
            {
                "cardDesc": "b",
                "cardTitle": "b",
                "comments": "b"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cards": [
            {
                "cardDesc": "c",
                "cardTitle": "c",
                "comments": "c"
            },
            {
                "cardDesc": "d",
                "cardTitle": "d",
                "comments": "d"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var currList = 0;
var x = 1;
lists[currList].cards.splice(x, 1);
console.log(lists);
```